# Play Framework calling a Controller from Satndalone Java Program

Tags: playframework

Correct me If I am doing wrong, We need to connect use a Play Controller from standalone Java Program (Same as we do with applet <-> Sevlet)

I have used the below program to connect to a Controller and sending a string as URL Parameter

```
  public class Sample {

public static void main(String args[]){
    uploadData("data");

}

private static void uploadData(String data){
    try{
        URLConnection con = getConnection();
        System.out.println("After Connection to callParseData");

        OutputStream outstream = con.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outstream);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();


        String output = "";
        // >>>Below Code is Throwing Invalida Header <<<<
        InputStream instr = con.getInputStream();           
        ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(instr);
        output = (String) inputFromServlet.readUTF();
        System.out.println("--out---"+output);
        inputFromServlet.close();
        instr.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static URLConnection getConnection()
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    URL urlServlet = new URL("http://localhost:9000/Transactions
                              /parseData?data=samuel");
    URLConnection con = urlServlet.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    //con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-java-serialized-object");
    return con;
}
```

}

And Method in Play Controller looks like:

```
   public static void parseData(){
    String data = params.get("data");
    System.out.println("Parse Data Called Data >> \t"+data);
     //Send Response back to the Standalone Program <<<<<

}
```

Can Someone suggest if there is any way send response back in String format ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `renderText()` from your action.

Comment: Thanks Codemwnci,Have tried using renderText() but the problem is am using InputStream in standalone program to get the response. so it is throwing java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 53616D75...what might be the cause?